# Node.js Send 3D Model File to Client for Rendering (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, three.js

This should be simple but combining the pieces seems to be tricky. I have a very simple local node.js server, and in the client `index.html` I am using three.js to load and render a 3D model file (AMF in this example, following a tutorial almost exactly).

However I cannot get the file to send to the client when requested, in my `app.js`. Relevant code below:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index.html title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/build/three.js"></script> 
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/AMFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="//threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    alert("asdf");
    var socket = io();
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    init();
    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x999999 ) );
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
        // Z is up for objects intended to be 3D printed.
        camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        camera.position.set( 0, -9, 6 );
        camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 ) );
        scene.add( camera );
        var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 25, 1.0, 0xffffff, 0x555555 );
        grid.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), 90 * ( Math.PI/180 ) );
        scene.add( grid );
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x999999 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        /* PROBLEM AREA BELOW: */

        var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader(); 
        loader.load('/rook.amf', function ( amfobject ) { 
            scene.add( amfobject );
            render();
        } );

        /* When I use res.sendFile, I get an error 'file not found' on client side */
        /* When I use res.write(), I get no result and don't see anything, but no error. */

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
        controls.target.set( 0, 1.2, 2 );
        controls.update();
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        alert("end of init") 
    }
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        render();
    }
    function render() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var THREE = require('three');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname);
console.log("publicPath: "+String(publicPath))
console.log("__dirname: "+String(__dirname))
app.use(express.static('/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/rook.amf', function(req, res) {
    console.log('test1 ::  '+String(__dirname + '\\rook.amf'))
    res.write(__dirname + '\\rook.amf'); // I've tried both res.sendFile (error), and res.write (no 3D model loaded, but no error)
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And yes I triped-checked that rook.amf is where it is. For reference, when I try `res.sendFile` call with same arguments I get:

`THREE.AMFLoader: Error loading AMF - no AMF document found.`

Basically I need a way to send 3D model files to that client, so they can render it in the browser on client side code that I am to later write.

Comment: if you already use `express.static` then why do you override the route?

Comment: First ensure you can get to the file. Navigating your browser to `localhost:3000/rook.amf` should trigger a download. If it does not, there is a problem with your express setup. If it DOES download, ensure the file downloaded matches the one you expect. If everything is good from there, then there must be a problem with the loader.

Comment: @Onheiron I'm trying different things because nothing has worked yet.

Comment: @TheJim01 I cannot, it just keeps "loading" (spinning icon on browser favicon tab location) and nothing happens at `localhost:3000/rook.amf`. What could be wrong with my express setup?

Comment: @TheJim01 Actually after some time I got the following: `GET http://localhost:3000/rook.amf net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)`. This seems like something to work with, though I don't understand where to do from here.